# Installing Ubuntu on a Chinese Zentality - Zen Pro laptop

Tags: uefi, bios, secure-boot

I need to install Ubuntu 18.04 (or any other doesn't matter) on my Chinese laptop and it's starting to look impossible to me.

I hope someone is able to help me do that.

- Device Brand: Zentality - Zen Pro
- OS: Preinstalled Windows 10
- RAM: 2 GB
- Storage: 32 GB
- BIOS: American Megatrends 5.011
- Compliancy: UEFI 2.4

I got Ubuntu 18.08 on a USB.

I've tried everything I came across online, but nothing worked. Secure boot didn't show up anywhere in my BIOS to be able to turn it off. Booting from the USB never worked. I even took it to an Indian tech maintenance shop and 2 days later they called me saying they couldn't do it.

Any advice?

Comment: Advice: Return the laptop and get a refund. Buy a better laptop that Ubuntu CAN be installed upon. Avoid that manufacturer in the future. If the BIOS is locked down so you cannot boot the installer, then you simply cannot install Ubuntu. End of story.